Very very basic python-binance ThreadedWebSocketManager example does not work... why?
I have an application that uses the binance api to trade and do some other stuff. The app worked fine for like 2 years, but one day it stopped working. So i decided to create a basic script to validate the core functionality of the api. I did everything exactly like its described in several offical docs and tutorials but its still not working as expected. Here is my code:
from binance import Client, ThreadedWebsocketManager

api_key = 'my_key'
api_secret = 'my_secret'

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

def process_message(msg):
    print("message type: {}".format(msg['e']))
    print(msg)

twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret)
twm.start()

ret = twm.start_kline_socket(callback=process_message, symbol='BTCEUR', interval='1m')
print(ret)

twm.join()

So, what happens at all? The twm is created and my print statement returns
btceur@kline_1m
thats all. I expected the script to call the process_message func every 1 minute, but it does not get called after a 1 min session has completed.
I have seen some similar troubles with older versions, have tried all possible solutions but I wasn´t able to fix it.
I am using the latest python-binance version, v1.0.19 - 2023-08-11 and python 3.12.3

python 3.12 is not well supported by all libraries.
You should use python 3.11 for production.
You can also try to upgrade all dependencies, especially aiohttp.

Thanks! Actually downgrading python to 3.11 solved my problem.
